# problem in converting tensorflow 1.x code to tensorflow 2.x

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I have a code in tf 1.x which I have converted in tf 2.x using 'tf upgrade v2.....' command but
there is 1 segment which I am having trouble in converting,i.e.

```
x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, None, 4])
y=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, None, 3])
```

I want to change the above two lines such that eager execution is not disabled

and one more line which is:

```
conv1 = slim.conv2d(input, 32, [3, 3], rate=1, activation_fn=lrelu, scope='g_conv1_1')
```

In the above line I don't want to use keras.layers.conv2D but I want to use tf.nn.conv2d().